# create executable jar including external jar file from Netbeans 8.0.2 and java 8

Tags: java-8, netbeans-8

I want to create executable jar file which includes my external jar files,
I am using Netbeans 8.0.2 and Java 8
I tried updating build.xml using solution provided on internet and stackoverflow,
But external jars files are not getting included into my single executable jar file.
I have tried this too

```
<target name="package-for-store" depends="jar">
    <property name="store.jar.name" value="myProject"/>
    <property name="store.dir" value="store"/>
    <property name="store.jar" value="${store.dir}/${store.jar.name}.jar"/>
    <echo message="Packaging ${application.title} into a single JAR at ${store.jar}"/>
    <delete dir="${store.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${store.dir}"/>
    <jar destfile="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar" filesetmanifest="skip">
        <zipgroupfileset dir="dist" includes="*.jar"/>
        <zipgroupfileset dir="dist/lib" includes="*.jar"/>
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
    <zip destfile="${store.jar}">
        <zipfileset src="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"
        excludes="META-INF/*.SF, META-INF/*.DSA, META-INF/*.RSA"/>
    </zip>
    <delete file="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"/>
</target>
```

I have also tried this

[How to build a fat jar using Netbeans](http://arunasujith.blogspot.com/2011/08/how-to-build-fat-jar-using-netbeans.html)

it created a single jar file but it doesn't include my external dependency.
Can anyone help me on how can I include my external jars into single executable jar using `Netbeans 8.0.2` and `java8`

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the answer,
 I used below configuration in build.xml

```
<target name="package-for-store" depends="jar">
    <property name="store.jar.name" value="DocumentProtector"/>
    <property name="store.dir" value="store"/>
    <property name="store.jar" value="${store.dir}/${store.jar.name}.jar"/>
    <echo message="Packaging ${application.title} into a single JAR at ${store.jar} mainclass ${main.class}"/>
    <delete dir="${store.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${store.dir}"/>
    <jar destfile="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar" filesetmanifest="skip">
        <zipgroupfileset dir="dist" includes="*.jar"/>
        <zipgroupfileset dir="dist/lib" includes="*.jar"/>
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
    <zip destfile="${store.jar}">
        <zipfileset src="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"
        excludes="META-INF/*.SF, META-INF/*.DSA, META-INF/*.RSA"/>
    </zip>
    <delete file="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"/>
</target>
```

after `clean+build`
right click `build.xml` and goto `Other target` and click on `package-for-store`
but after doing this I was getting wrong main class
so after little research i found the solution to change main class
go to `project folder -> nbproject and open project.properties` file
and change main.class to you mail class file name with package name
like this  `main.class=com.test.package.MainClass`
and `clean+build` and again
right click `build.xml` and goto `Other target` and click on `package-for-store`